# Is it possible to destroy factions?

Tags: fallout-4

When I heard

> That the Botherhood of Steel wanted to wipe out the railroad

I thought that since I'm Level 30 and have good stuff I could go in and absolutely wreck that place but I'm wondering if it's even possible?

Comment: Why the all caps?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, it's possible to destroy factions.

To do so you can join one of the factions (or more than one) and during they main quest line mission against other factions (which are usually related to wiping out their headquarters) will appear. Quest names are the following.

If you side up with BoS:

- Tactical Thinking - against Railroad;
- The Nuclear Options - against Institute.

If you side up with Railroad:

- Rockets' Red Glare - against BoS;
- The Nuclear Option - against Institute.

If you side up with Institute:

- End of the Life - against  Railroad;
- Airship Down - against BoS.

If you side up with Minutemen:

- The Nuclear Option - against Institute;
- With Our Powers Combined - against BoS.

See details on these quests [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_quests).

And also you can go to any faction headquarters and kill everyone there without any quests.

Comment: Its not only possible but  mandatory to destroy at least one faction to complete the main storyline - You can destroy ONLY Institute if you go carefully with quests i.e. go with BoS till you get "Tactical thinking", switch to Institute quests till "Mass Fusion" then switch to BoS by talking to BoS leader and take down Institute while leaving Railorad whole. Unless it has been patched... :/